# ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar for Numpy Select

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

`newX` and `breaks` are numpy ndarray of shape (24000L,) and (7L,) respectively. newX is within range of (0,9). `yvals` is a lookup table based on breaks segmented into 10000 (nsegs) samples called `xvals`(not used here).

```
deltaX=(breaks[-1]-breaks[0])/nsegs
xvals=[x+i*deltaX for i in range(nsegs+1)]
```

Both breaks and yvals are monotonically increasing. Basically, I want yvals[0] to be returned when newX value is less than the breaks[0], and yvals[-1] when newX value is higher than breaks[-1]. For other values I want it to generate an index for yvals corresponding to a point closest to xval (an example is shown below)
When I do the following:

```
condlist=[newX<=breaks[0] , newX < breaks[-1] , newX >= breaks[-1]]
choicelist=[yvals[0] , yvals[((newX-breaks[0]))/deltax.astype(int).item()] , yvals[-1]]
ans = np.select(condlist,choicelist)
```

I get the error in the choicelist line -

> ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

How can I fix this?

Comment: Read the [docstring of the item() method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) more carefully.  In particular, note the case when no arguments are given.  It says "in this case, the method only works for arrays with one element".

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser : I understand that. But I am not able to find any other way to make numpy select work

Comment: @zaq : I am sorry zac. Does the edit work now?

Comment: It's an improvement but the title would be better if it described the actual task being done. The error comes up whenever a scalar is expected but an array is received, which happens for many different reasons. The "Related" column is full of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for numpy.select here, your goal can be simply stated

```
choicelist = yVals[ix]
```

where ix is an array of indices to be computed. What I see is newX being transformed linearly, rounded to integers, and *clipped* so that indices do not go beyond the range 0...len(yVals)-1. All this is expressed by

```
ix = np.clip(np.around((newX-breaks[0])/deltax).astype(int), 0, len(yVals)-1)
```

where

- `np.around((newX-breaks[0])/deltax)` rounds the result of computation to nearest integer. Without the rounding .astype(int) would floor it, which is less desirable.
- `np.clip(..., 0, len(yVals)-1)` clips the results so that all indices are valid.